# How to access servlet and download attachment?

Tags: java, servlets, apache-poi, content-disposition

I have the following code snippet that tries to make an HTTP call to my servlet:

```
    try {
        // Construct data
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("rpt_type", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportType, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_project", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportProject, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_mrv_creator", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportMrvCreator, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_gi_recipient", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportGiRecipient, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_plant", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportPlant, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_sloc", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportStorageLoc, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_gi_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportGiNo, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("date_sap_gi_fr", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportDateGiFrom, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("date_sap_gi_to", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportDateGiTo, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_partno", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportPartNo, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("rpt_so_no", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportSvcOrderNo, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("date_scan_fr", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportDateScanFrom, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("date_scan_to", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(reportDateScanTo, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("[data]\n" + data);

        // Send data
        String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/aerobook/GIStatusReportDownload?" + data;
        System.out.println("[url] " + urlString);
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        //conn.setDoOutput(true);
        //OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        //wr.write(data);
        //wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        //wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

My debug output:

```
[data]
rpt_type=d&rpt_project=aaa&rpt_mrv_creator=bbb&rpt_gi_recipient=ccc&rpt_plant=ddd&rpt_sloc=eee&rpt_gi_no=fff&date_sap_gi_fr=02%2F05%2F2012&date_sap_gi_to=03%2F05%2F2012&rpt_partno=ggg&rpt_so_no=hhh&date_scan_fr=26%2F05%2F2012&date_scan_to=31%2F05%2F2012
[url] http://localhost:8080/aerobook/GIStatusReportDownload?rpt_type=d&rpt_project=aaa&rpt_mrv_creator=bbb&rpt_gi_recipient=ccc&rpt_plant=ddd&rpt_sloc=eee&rpt_gi_no=fff&date_sap_gi_fr=02%2F05%2F2012&date_sap_gi_to=03%2F05%2F2012&rpt_partno=ggg&rpt_so_no=hhh&date_scan_fr=26%2F05%2F2012&date_scan_to=31%2F05%2F2012
```

On my servlet (in a separate file from the code above), I generate an Excel file for download:

```
    res.setContentType(sContentType);
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + sExcelFileName + "\"");
    OutputStream oOutStrm = res.getOutputStream();
    wbBook.write(oOutStrm);
    oOutStrm.close();
```

My issue here is that from the URL generated by my code (as shown in the debug output above), I can access my servlet and I manage to get the Save-As dialog.

I'd like to get the contents of the file generated for use within my code. Is there any way I can get the attachment from my code, in byte stream or any other format?

---

Edit #3: Cleaned up the top

Comment: did u check your url in browser?

Comment: Yes I did. In my code segment above, `System.out.println(data);` produced the string `key1=value1&key2=value2`. What I did was, I appended "?" to my URL, followed by this string. The result I got was `http://localhost/MyProject/MyServlet?key1=value1&key2=value2`. I entered this into the browser address bar, I was able to download my excel file. I want to get the contents of the excel file on my code, but so far it's not working.

Comment: ok. check this sample http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/file-url-download.shtml

Comment: Provide code snippet of `wbBook.write()` method

Comment: @Quio I looked up the link and tried the code inside. It didn't work =/

Comment: @ohseekay - *`Is there any way I can get the attachment from my code, in byte stream or any other format?`* Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`I want to get the contents of the excel file on my code, but so far it's not working.`*

I find no errors in the code.
I believe you want to convert content from input stream to an `HSSFWorkbook` object.
Following code snippet will help you on it.

```
java.net.URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();  
java.io.InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook workBook = new org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook( is );  
System.out.println( "Number of Sheets: " + workBook.getNumberOfSheets() );  
org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt( 0 );  
System.out.println( "Sheet Name: " + sheet.getSheetName() );  

// rest of your code to handle the captured workBook
// cheers
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the URI into the browser, you are doing a GET request. Your client Java code however produces a POST request, and sends the parameters in the body, not the URI.

You may want to look at an HTTP trace and compare.

Comment: This sounds reasonable! I'm not sure how to do an HTTP trace, but how do I go about doing a GET request in my Java code?

Comment: Re: edit #2, I think my code is doing a GET request now but no it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Check `wbBook.write(oOutStrm);` whether anything has been written into outputStream, also you need call `oOutStrm.flash()` before close it.

Comment: I'm very sure that there's data written into it.

As I mentioned in my question, when I access my servlet via the URL, I get a Save-As dialog and I'm able to save the file. However, I'm not able to replicate this on my code.

Comment: you send this `URL url = new URL("http://localhost/MyProject/MyServlet");` from your code, without any parameters, that is not same as you typed in browser.

Comment: The three lines after `conn.setDoOutput(true);` are supposed to send the data to my servlet, aren't they? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It does not like you thought. Try to send out the same URL that you typed in browser. Or try to add some code in `doPost` method of your servlet, you may send out a post request.

Comment: Made some changes to match what would have worked on the browser, but still nothing

Comment: try to comment `conn.setDoOutput(true);`, and added some debug info in to you servlet, you should make sure your request has been handled by the same method in your servlet.

Comment: Commented out that line, newer version of code with debug lines (they were there all along) put up

Comment: oh, I mean add some debug info into your servlet, you make sure the request has sent to doGet method.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the problem lies at  `OutputStream oOutStrm = res.getOutputStream();`.

I bet `res` is `HttpServletResponse` and it returns a `ServletOutputStream` suitable for writing binary data in the response. The servlet container does not encode the binary data

Check [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29)

So, You might not be getting anything except fileName.

In Servlet Try

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("c:/excel/Book1.xls");
workBook.write(stream);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to make changes to the servlet, due to certain reasons :(

Comment: Check edited answer. You have to write something to `OutputStream` else you will get nothing as output.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Right now `wbBook.write(oOutStrm);` works, the content type is set to `application/ms-excel`. The servlet code is inherited by a lot of children classes so it's very hard for me to justify changing the code there.

Comment: How one can come to know that you have inherited other code ? I have answered based on your post and you had not mentioned for the same also. Anyway hope your problem is solved